# Optimizing a SQL/NHibernate query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I have a table ReadNews as follows:

```
id: int
User_id: int
News_id : int
DateRead : Datetime
FacebookUser_id: int
```

this is stored in a table.

I am getting my friends list of id, via rest call to fb and storing as `IEnumerable<string>` in the memory.

I need to find the latest news that my friends `(IEnumerable<string>)` read ordered by datetime descending. I m using NHibernate.

What s the most efficient way of building this query?

Essentially I have all the read news by fb users, but i want to get only the ones read by my friends.

I was thinking of doing:

```
select * from readnews where FacebookUser_id in (IEnumerable<string>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, if you are all appropriately indexed up then using IN(x,y,z) is pretty performant and linq/nh should intemperate it fine for you. Try out nhibernate rino to be sure though.

http://nhprof.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you found any performance problem with it? top n + index on FacebookUser_id should do just fine.

It all depends on amount of data you have, etc. Ask yourself if you don't see any problems with it, aren't you trying premature optimization?